# HTML::DOM stops forks module from working

Tags: perl, fork

I have encountered a strange error. When I use [`HTML::DOM`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aDOM) and [`forks`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks) module at the same time, the `forks` module doesn't work properly.

Strange thing is, this occurs only at some machines, not on others. Example:

```
use forks;
use HTML::DOM;

$|=1;

print "before\n";
threads->new( sub {    
    $|=1;
    print "inside\n";
} );

print "after\n";

sleep(3600);
```

I see only `before` and `after`, never `inside` on standard output. It works with standard `threads`, but I don't want to use it.

If I comment out the `use HTML::DOM;` line, it suddenly starts working. So, my questions are,

1. Is it really a bug?
2. If it is a bug, where to report it? Is it a bug of `HTML::DOM`, `forks`, both...?

edit: it happens only with 5.8.8 perl, not with 5.10.0.

Comment: Its working fine for me here. Perl 5.12.2 on Linux, HTML-DOM 0.045, forks 0.34.

Comment: I think it is the 5.8.8 thing. Well, I am contacting the author of the forks module now. I just first asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `forks` is claiming to provide the same interface as `threads` I'd be more inclined to report it against `forks` over `HTML::DOM`. Especially since the `forks` is the one doing the deep magic, whereas `HTML::DOM` is just a normal everyday module. Its not likely the `HTML::DOM` authors will have any idea what you're on about.

Answer (score -2):

Problem "solved".

I had a weird settings in `$PERLLIB` and `$PERL5LIB`, that linked to non-existing directories or directories with outdated libraries. Once I fixed that, `forks` started working as it should.

So, if you have similar troubles with `forks`, check your `$PERLLIB` and `$PERL5LIB`, if it links where it should link.

Comment: This really is nothing to do with `forks`. If your `PERL5LIB` is incorrect then your entire Perl installation has the potential to do the wrong thing no matter what your code does.